# PATCH request with AngularJS - Missing request header

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to send a PATCH request with angularjs to a spring rest backend. The backend is Ok with postman call's, but when I try to send from angular, I receive this:

"Missing request header 'Authorization' for method parameter of type String","path":"example/2"}"

Angular:

```
method: 'PATCH',
url: '/localhost:9001/example',
headers: {
   'Authorization': $scope.authenticationCode
},
data: $scope.test
```

This happens only with PATCH requests...

Comment: do you allow the headers to accept Authorization in backend and also add the options for the preflight?

Comment: Is "$scope.authenticationCode" String or number?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco 
Authorization is released. Where I release preflight options?

Comment: @hurricane authenticationCode is a string value

Comment: in your bakcend you need to allow all headers, browser when detect custom header always send first http options to the backend. to make some kind of handshake if pass then do the other http reques in your case the patch

Comment: @JesusCarrasco My backend configuration:


response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization");

Comment: your backend is php with some framework or with other language?, can see the route definition for the patch method?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco No, the backend is java with spring.